# Equivalent of SQL Server's SYSPROCESS in POSTGRESQL

Tags: database-migration, postgresql-10, system-tables

I have a query in SQL Server:

```
 SELECT kpid,hostprocess
 FROM master..sysprocesses
```

I want to know the equivalent code of this in POSTGRESQL.

Thanks!

Comment: [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW)?

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name